# Just show recyclerView after all items are drawn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I would like to know if there is any built-in function in the recyclerview where I can show it only when all items are drawn?

I tried the recyclerview.post {} function, but it still keeps drawing the items in real-time. As I have hundreds of them and they are quite complex, they are drawn live for the user.
I would like to show it only when it is ready.